Prove that $W^{\bot}$ is also the invariant subspace of $f$
Let $f$ be the equidistant transformation over the inner product space $V$, and $W$ be the $r$-dimensional invariant subspace of $f$. Prove that $W^{\bot}$ is also an invariant subspace of $f$.
I met this problem in my homework, and my proof is:
$\forall \boldsymbol{\alpha }\in W$, since $W$ is the invariant subspace of $f$, we have $f\left( \boldsymbol{\alpha } \right) \in W$. Since $f$ is the equidistant transformation over the inner product space $V$, $\forall \boldsymbol{\beta }\in W^{\bot}$ we have
$$
\left< f\left( \boldsymbol{\alpha } \right) ,f\left( \boldsymbol{\beta } \right) \right> =\left< \boldsymbol{\alpha },\boldsymbol{\beta } \right> =0,
$$
which means $f\left( \boldsymbol{\beta } \right) \in W^{\bot}$. Thus $W^{\bot}$ is also the invariant subspace of $f$.
Is my proof correct? I didn't use the condition that $W$ is the $r$-dimensional, so I am comfused.

Your proof doesn't quite work. You have shown that, for all $\beta \in W^\perp$ and all $\alpha \in W$, $f(\alpha) \perp f(\beta)$. This shows that $f(\beta) \in (f(W))^\perp$. Now, $W$ is invariant under $f$, but this just means that $f(W) \subseteq W$. It does not necessarily mean that $f(W) = W$. For example, a linear operator $T$ with a non-trivial kernel $W$ will map $T(W) = \{0\} \subsetneq W$. The kernel is still invariant, but it collapses under application of $T$.
However, we can rectify this by using the fact that $W$ has finite dimension, and $f$ is orthogonal. You can use orthogonality to show that, if $w_1, \ldots, w_r$ is an orthonormal basis for $W$, then $f(w_1), \ldots, f(w_r)$ is an orthonormal set in $f(W) \subseteq W$. Being orthonormal (or just orthogonal) implies that it is linearly independent, and since it is contained in $W$ with dimension $r$, it must be a basis for $W$. This implies $f(W) = W$, and your proof holds from there.

Thank you very much, your explanation is clear and thorough!

You're welcome!
